# Maximo Automation Script for Integration

Tags: xml, integration, jython, maximo

I really need help, I can't seem to find an answer to this. What I want to happen is during the inbound of data from the xml to the system, the PRNUM will be queried to the PRLINE object (which is the child object of the PR) so that I can get the CONTRACTNUM field, but I cant seem to get a value from it. I always get an error of Nonetype because its empty.

```
from psdi.server import MXServer
def beforeMboData(ctx):
    mbo = ctx.getMbo()
    struc = ctx.getData()
    prlineSet = MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet('PRLINE', ctx.getUserInfo())
    prlineSet.setWhere("PRNUM = '"+struc.getCurrentData('PRNUM')+"'")
    prLine = prlineSet.moveFirst()
    contractSet = MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet('CONTRACT', ctx.getUserInfo())
    contractSet.setWhere("CONTRACTNUM = '"+prLine.getString('CONTRACTNUM')+"'")
    contractRec = contractSet.moveFirst()
    struc.setCurrentData('CONTRACTID',contractRec.getInt('CONTRACTID'))
```

And the xml looks like this:

```
<max:PR action='AddChange'>
    <max:PRNUM>SMPL</max:PRNUM>
    <max:SITEID>BEDFORD</max:SITEID>
    <max:VENDOR>JOHNS</max:VENDOR>
    <max:PRLINE action='AddChange'>
        <max:PRLINENUM>1</max:PRLINENUM>
        <max:ITEMNUM>01231</max:ITEMNUM>
        <!-- I forgot the other fields here -->
        <max:CONTRACTNUM>X1C1</max:CONTRACTNUM>
        <max:CONTRACTID></max:CONTRACTID>
    </max:PRLINE>
</max:PR>
```

The CONTRACTID field is just for testing because I was trying to see if I will retrieve some data and I will remove it soon. I'm new to this and I also dont know how to get the ChildObject Data from to xml with the automation script to make it easier. I can't find anything on Google about something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of trial and errors here's what worked

```
from psdi.server import MXServer
def beforeCreateMboSet(ctx):
    mbo = ctx.getMbo()
    struc = ctx.getData()
    try:
        contractSet = MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet('CONTRACT', ctx.getUserInfo())
        prLine = struc.getChildrenData('PRLINE')
        prCount = len(prLine)
        count = 0
        while count < prCount:
            struc.setAsCurrent(prLine,count)
            contractNum = struc.getCurrentData('CONTRACTNUM')
            contractSet.setWhere("CONTRACTNUM = '"+contractNum+"'")
            contractRec = contractSet.moveFirst()
            struc.setCurrentData('CONTRACTID',contractRec.getString('CONTRACTID'))
            count += 1
    finally:
        contractSet.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your PR already in the system? This looks like an incoming PR being *added* to the system. If that is the case, then the data is not in the database yet. Since you are getting a set from MXServer (which is generally not the desired way to do that), that means you are pulling the data out of the database (where it doesn't exist yet) and in a new transaction, instead of the incoming message.

Additionally, I forget which hooks/methods are available to integration classes, but beforeMboData seems like the wrong one for your needs. That *sounds* like (though I don't remember if this is true and can not look it up right now) that hook runs before it loads the data into the MBO object.

Comment: the PR is not yet in the system, but the contract record is already in there.

Comment: OK. That's your problem then. This: "prlineSet = MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet('PRLINE', ctx.getUserInfo())
    prlineSet.setWhere("PRNUM = '"+struc.getCurrentData('PRNUM')+"'")
    prLine = prlineSet.moveFirst()" is going to return null (or None in Python) because it is pulling from existing data in the system and not from the incoming message.